# CakePHP Auth component - isAuthorized() function issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following isAuthorized() function in my students controller:

```
function isAuthorized() {
    $studentId = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $studentEmail = $this->Auth->user('email');
    if ($this->Auth->user('active') == 1 && $this->Auth->user('level_complete') != 1) {
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/classrooms/view';
        return true;
    } elseif (!$this->Student->hasPayed($studentId)) {
        $this->Session->write('Payment.student_id', $studentId);
        $this->Session->write('Payment.student_email', $studentEmail);
        $this->Session->write('Payment.examScore', $this->Student->getPlacementScore($studentId));
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'payments', 'action'=>'pay'));  
    } elseif ($this->Auth->user('level_complete') == 1) {
        $this->Session->write('Payment.student_id', $studentId);
        $this->Session->write('Payment.student_email', $studentEmail);
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'payments', 'action' => 'repay'));
    } else {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'students', 'action' => 'disabled'));
    }


    return false;
}
```

Basically, there are four possible states covered in this method:

1. The user is active and has not completed a level = Authorized
2. The user has not payed = Not Authorized
3. The user has completed a level and has to pay again = Not Authorized
4. The user account is not active

The problem I am having is that I have a login form in my header, and I can login from any controller. If I login from a controller other than the Students Controller, the isAuthorized() method is not called, and the user can login even though he shouldn't be able to.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: After checking the API's definition of the isAuthorized() method, I think that the method is only called when actions from the students controller are requested. Where else could I implement this logic then? Thanks

Comment: Are you using `beforeFilter()` at all?

Comment: yeah setting up the Auth component in beforeFilter(), but not for this logic. I though that the isAuthorized() method was called when the user tried to log in.

Comment: you have login action in every controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically put such logic in my `login()` method of my *Auth* controller (i.e. UsersController).

However, I don't believe that your understanding of `isAuthorized()` is incorrect. Unfortunately I do believe it is more difficult to wire up.

For example:

- As noted by **santiagobasulto**, you'll need to ensure you've configured `Auth->authorize = 'controller'`.
- If you are using *any* `beforeFilters()` be sure you are calling `parent::beforeFilter()`. It's possible that you've forgotten this in a key area keeping Cake from ever reaching your functions on other login actions.

Comment: How do you accomplish this in the login() method? You look up the user by email address from using the value in $this->data ? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Or you can call `Auth->login()` first, the use the exact code you have above. It's really up to you weather you do it before or after *login*. However, after *login* tends to make more sense as you've already ensured you have a valid user.

Answer (score 5):

You're messing things up. The isAuthorized() method is called only when the user is logged in.

This mean that cake separates the logic in two parts:

1) the user must log to see access the action is controlled with the `$this->Auth->allow()` method (inside the beforeFilter of your controller). This tells cake if the user must log to see the action or not.

2) The User must pass the isAuthorized() method. Only if $this->Auth->authorize is set to "controller".

So, if you want that users must be logged in to access action "X" from Controller C, in your C Controller you must put this code:

```
function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
}
```

After that, if you want to have more control over that (if the users role is "admin", for example) then you have to do that in your isAuthorized() method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. I need to test for specific conditions in associated to the User, for example, If the user has not submitted a payment, he should be redirected to the payment page after trying to login.

Comment: Then what you have to change is your login method! You must act different. Don't let him log in.

Comment: Should I write my own login() function, include all this logic and then manually log him in if he is authorized?

Comment: NO! First chek if you will let them log in. I'm sure you've created a login() method inside your UsersController that somewhere calls $this->Auth->login(). Before calling Auth->login(), check those conditions and that if you like, don't log him.

Comment: Yeah exactly. That's what I'll try to do. Gracias